# xslt for-each apply-templates troubles

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="c:richBody">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
          <div style="height:50px;" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have the code blurb above and need to do something in between the first c:richBody element and the second c:richBody.  It looks like when it is getting to applytemplates it just goes through all of them and then goes down the doc.  With what I have above the height 50 div gets placed above all the apply-templates.

Is there any way to do something inbetween the items that are getting apply-templates applied to them?

Comment: In the `<xsl:if>` is your intent to test for the first or for the second `c:richBody` ?

Comment: It might help if you showed more of the stylesheet, such as the entire `xsl:template` containing the `for-each`; also some input XML would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you are thinking in "C", where the first item has position()=0; the second has position()=1 ...

However, for XSLT you have to think like a sane person instead. The first item has position() = 1. To insert your div before the second item, your test should be if test="position()=2"

Answer (score 0):

As a guess, I'd say you want

```
<xsl:if test="position()>1">
```

which would give you a div between all the `c:richBody` tags.

Comment: I shy away from using `<` and `>` in XPath expressions because I can never remember which one makes the parser gag.  I'll use `position() != 1` in an instance like this, since it can't ever be less than 1.